# Nested json type won't serialize in jersey

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I'm running a dropwizard/jersey java restful web app.

I have an endpoint that is defined like this in `api.yaml`:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.1
basePath: /
schemes:
  - https
  - http
consumes:
- application/json
- application/x-protobuf
produces:
- application/json
- application/x-protobuf
paths:
  /v1/event:
    post:
      summary: receive a event
      operationId: receiveEvent ## this value names the generated Java method
      parameters:
        - name: event
          in: body
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Event"
      responses:
        200:
          description: success
          schema:
            type: object
            $ref: '#/definitions/EventResponse'

definitions:
  Stream:
    properties:
      vendor:
        type: "string"
  Event:
    properties:
      eventCity:
        type: "string"
      streams:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Stream"
  EventResponse:
    required:
      - statusCode
    properties:
      statusCode:
        type: "integer"
```

Endpoint is defined like so

```
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json", "application/x-protobuf" })
    @Produces({ "application/json", "application/x-protobuf" })
    @Path("/event")
    void receiveEvent(
            @Suspended AsyncResponse response,
            @Valid Event.EventModel  event
    );
```

When issuing json POST request, I cannot get the `streams` field to get serialized/deserialized property.

This is the payload

```
{
  "eventCity": "San Diego", 
  "streams": [
    {
      "vendor": "CBS"
    }
  ]
}
```

I test like this with `curl`

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"eventCity": "San Diego", "streams": [{"vendor": "CBS"}]}' https://localhost:8990/v1/event
```

In the server request handler:

```
@Override
public void receiveEvent(AsyncResponse response, Event.EventModel event) {
  System.out.println(event.getEventCity());
  System.out.println(event.getStreamCount()); // <-- this returns 0? why is the inner 'streams' list not getting serialized? it should have one element
}
```

And the output:

```
San Diego
0
```

Another observation, is that when I issue the same post, but with a protobuf payload, it works. The streams list is populated.

The protobuf was generated like so

```
// create proto
Stream.StreamModel stream = Stream.StreamModel.newBuilder()
        .setVendor("CBS")
        .build();
Event.EventModel event = Event.EventModel.newBuilder()
        .setEventCity("San Diego")
        .addStream(stream)
        .build();

// write to file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/jameswierzba/temp/proto.out");
stream.writeTo(fos);
```

The output in the endpoint is as expected:

```
San Diego
1
```

This is the full generated code for the `Event` class: https://gist.github.com/wierzba3/84face6c21c4fb6ce554f90707ba6ef9

This is the full generated doe for the `Stream` class: https://gist.github.com/wierzba3/32664312df87c64049b281daab928f94

Comment: Please add the full EventModel /Event class

Comment: @satyesht that is auto generated from api.yaml -- do you really want me to past the full generated code?

Comment: Is the complete api definition of Event shown? I’m trying to understand where streamCount comes from.

Comment: The example payload is still wrong, now the curly braces missing. Also, the example curl is missing the [ ]

Comment: @JohnWilliams updated the payloads again and also double checked that I'm still seeing the error locally.

Comment: @JohnWilliams yes it is a complete definition. the thing that is missing is the auto-generated protobuf code that is generated by the framework that is used in the API event handlers. one such auto-generated function is that `getStreamCount()` function you are referring to

Comment: I will get the generated code over to you

Comment: @JohnWilliams The auto generated java protobuf code is provided at the bottom of the question

Comment: What tool did you use to generate the Java stubs from openapi spec?

Comment: Can you add System.out.println(event. getStreamList().size()); and System.out.println(event. getStreamList().get(0)); to the receiveEvent implementation and update response.

Comment: @JohnWilliams the output for that is `0` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` respectively. regarding generation of java stubs from open api spec, I need to dig into that a little bit to figure out how that works -- ill get back to you on that

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same class as the payload for protobuf and json.

If you inspect the [Event](https://gist.github.com/wierzba3/84face6c21c4fb6ce554f90707ba6ef9) generated for protobuf processing you will notice that the the stream is stored as `stream_` and has a `setStream` that returns a `Builder` as follows. A JSON deserialiser can't work with it:

```
  /**
   * <code>repeated .com.apple.amp.social.linearmasterplaylist.refresh.model.StreamModel stream = 2;</code>
   */
  public Builder setStream(
      int index, com.apple.amp.social.linearmasterplaylist.refresh.model.Stream.StreamModel value) {
    if (streamBuilder_ == null) {
      if (value == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
      }
      ensureStreamIsMutable();
      stream_.set(index, value);
      onChanged();
    } else {
      streamBuilder_.setMessage(index, value);
    }
    return this;
  }
```

A JSON deserialiser (probably jackson-databind) needs a definition of Event like [this generated with openapi-generator-cli](https://gist.github.com/KoosieDeMoer/d61caa3c85a83acfafffa2c626b27084). In this case the stream and its setter look like this: (note that the `@JsonProperty("streams")` is redundant as the property is named `streams`)

```
  @JsonProperty("streams")
  @Valid
  private List<Stream> streams = null;
```

and

```
  public void setStreams(List<Stream> streams) {
    this.streams = streams;
  }
```

I have included the other model definitions [here](https://gist.github.com/KoosieDeMoer/4a95713ce7474c2dedcf8f052d7403fd) to allow you to try them with you controller to show that JSON is correctly consumed.

It is possible to write code to inspect the incoming media type and fork the processing. Eg the following generated by openapi-generator. I would recommend a separate controller method for each media type and some sort of mapping so that a single service layer call will suffice.

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/v1/event",
    produces = { "application/json", "application/x-protobuf" },
    consumes = { "application/json", "application/x-protobuf" }
)
default ResponseEntity<EventResponse> receiveEvent(
    @Parameter(name = "event", description = "") @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) Event event
) {
    getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
        for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
            if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                String exampleString = "{ \"statusCode\" : 0 }";
                ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                break;
            }
            if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/x-protobuf"))) {
                String exampleString = "Custom MIME type example not yet supported: application/x-protobuf";
                ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/x-protobuf", exampleString);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

}
```

On a separate note, but I doubt it will help: it looks like the protobuf is using stream (singular) (eg getStreamList()) and the swagger get uses streams (plural).

Comment: your answer did not turn out to be the fix however you were onto something when you pointed out that the generated variable name was `stream_` -- it was using the type of the list element as the list variable name which was a bug

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue turned out to be a bug in our companies internal implementation of the code generation module.

Workflow looks like this: api.yaml specified -> .proto file generated -> .java code generated.

To be explicit. Using the schema in question. Note I changed the list to have name `myStreamArrayInput` to illustrate the issue at hand.

```
  Event:
    properties:
      eventCity:
        type: "string"
      myStreamArrayInput:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Stream"
```

This would generate a proto like this:

```
message Event {
    optional string eventCity = 1;
    /*
        this name should be `myStreamArrayInput` or something 
        close to it. but it is using the name of the TYPE 
        instead of the name specified by the dev in api.yaml
    */
    repeated StreamModel stream; 
}
```

And then this would generate a java class like this

```
public final class Event {

    public static final class EventModel extends
      com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 implements EventModelOrBuilder {
        private EventModel() {
            eventCity_ = "";
            stream_ = ""; 
        }
    }

}
```

YMMV, since this is an bug in our own internal code generation engine

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getJson() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject("foo", new NestedObject("bar"));
        myObjects.add(myObject);
        String json;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObjects);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

    private static class MyObject {
        private String name;
        private NestedObject nestedObject;

        public MyObject(String name, NestedObject nestedObject) {
            this.name = name;
            this.nestedObject = nestedObject;
        }

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @JsonProperty("nested_object")
        public NestedObject getNestedObject() {
            return nestedObject;
        }
    }

    private static class NestedObject {
        private String value;

        public NestedObject(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @JsonProperty("value")
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).